# Scripting a Mouseover and click event

Tags: click, mouseover, katalon-studio

I'm trying to write a script in Katalon Studio where I have to mouseover and click a specific div. The element is only available when the mouse is hovering over a specific div. If I run the two commands sequentially, it doesn't work correctly. I'm working if I can chain them, something like:

I've tried targeting the elements in sequential steps, but it doesn't work right, I've tried chaining them (as shown above), but syntax doesn't work in groovy that way.

```
WebUI.mouseOver(findTestObject('blah')).click(findTestObject('myElement'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using Selenium's Action class:

```
import com.kms.katalon.core.webui.driver.DriverFactory
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Action
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions

WebUI.openBrowser("the page")
WebDriver driver = DriverFactory.getWebDriver() 

Actions builder = new Actions(driver)
Action howerAndClick = builder.moveToElement("the web element").click().build()
```

Note that you might need to convert the test object to a test element.